# HDD converted to CoreStorage, even after Internet Recovery

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility

When I used Mountain Lion, I had a 3TB HDD that used the HFS+ file system, and I was able to create two partitions on my one HDD both of them storing certain stuff. I could also do this in Mavericks as well, but when I upgraded to Yosemite, I was not able to modify the partitions and can use no more than 1.5TB. I thought that this was the result of a botched BootCamp uninstallation, but I found out that it was because the drive was converted to CoreStorage. I did an IR which saw me downgrade back to ML, but unfortunately this did nothing to fix the problem, and in Disk Utility itself, everything is disabled.

[image]

As you can see, there are two sections. The top section is 699.16GB in size, while the bottom one is 801GB. I want to use all my 3TB devoted to the OS. I went into the terminal and entered **diskutil cs list** and this is what I came up with:

```
CoreStorage logical volume groups (1 found)
|
+-- Logical Volume Group 4E150AA1-CC1F-4962-A337-D540D3217D9D
    =========================================================
    Name:         Macintosh HD
    Status:       Online
    Size:         1500598398976 B (1.5 TB)
    Free Space:   0 B (0 B)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume B06E3783-7DD4-40E1-8A45-041BD78BBE88
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    0
    |   Disk:     disk0s2
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     699161858048 B (699.2 GB)
    |
    +-< Physical Volume 8A3D9D72-571C-48ED-9D18-710F11D4C1BE
    |   ----------------------------------------------------
    |   Index:    1
    |   Disk:     disk0s4
    |   Status:   Online
    |   Size:     801436540928 B (801.4 GB)
    |
    +-> Logical Volume Family 9ED51F70-CE25-416E-BDF8-A7255223913E
        ----------------------------------------------------------
        Encryption Status:       Unlocked
        Encryption Type:         None
        Conversion Status:       NoConversion
        Conversion Direction:    -none-
        Has Encrypted Extents:   No
        Fully Secure:            No
        Passphrase Required:     No
        |
        +-> Logical Volume 395B7D2E-2FA5-45D9-B175-84EE93307015
            ---------------------------------------------------
            Disk:               disk1
            Status:             Online
            Size (Total):       1499994402816 B (1.5 TB)
            Size (Converted):   -none-
            Revertible:         No
            LV Name:            Macintosh HD
            Volume Name:        Macintosh HD
            Content Hint:       Apple_HFS
```

I tried several solutions but to no avail, probably because it said "Revertible: No". So maybe I have no choice but to delete it instead then attempt to resize?

Comment: Your drive can't be "converted to Core Storage" because CS is a [system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_Storage), not a format, that resides between the disk partition and the file system.  That said, if you had two partitions, CS wouldn't just grab them and combine them.  There seems to be some missing details here.

Comment: "Your drive can't be "converted to Core Storage"""
But it says "1.5TB Core Storage Logical Volume Group" when you hover the mouse over the first line in the left pane.

"There seems to be some missing details here. "
Such as...?